# How to prevent insertion into a table using triggers

Tags: mysql

I'm firing a trigger before insertion of data into a table. If the data doesn't meet certain criteria then I need to insert into a log file and prevent the insertion of data into the original table. How to do this? I tried to achieve this by using signals but it is preventing the insertion into log file.(getting roll back)

Comment: What are the criteria for non-insertion?

Comment: Like: user CGPA is below the required, pre-requisite to take a course is not cleared

Comment: I ask because unique indexes are a great way to enforce data integrity if  something about the insert criteria can be made unique

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: That's why I'm trying to clarify specifically what the criteria for non-insertion are, there's general ways to do what you want and there's better given circumstance ways.

Comment: There are 2 tables: takes(student_id, course_id, semester, year), course_offerings(course_code, course_name, course_prerequisite). When a student wants to register for a course from course_offerings , before inserting data into takes table, I want to check if he cleared the pre-requisite for that course mentioned in course_offerings. If he has not cleared then I need to make an entry in "pending" table and prevent insertion into takes table. All the attributes in takes table form a primary key whereas course_code alone forms as a primary key for course_offerings.

Comment: Do such checks in the application logic, not in the database layer.

Comment: Above is correct, that type of validation is far easier to do at the application level.